# Bayeux tapestry and D-Day beaches

Tags: france, paris, normandy

Starting from Paris, I want to make a one-day trip combining a visit the Bayeux tapestry museum and with a tour of some of the D-Day beaches. How can I travel between Paris, Bayeux and the beaches? Which beaches would I have time to visit?

Comment: Your question has been closed as construction of a travel itinerary, but that's not applicable here. How much time it takes and what the travel options are is an objectively answerable question. I've rephrased your question to focus on the objective aspects, hopefully it'll get reopened.

Comment: Do you want to take public transport, to rent a car, or either? Bayeux is easily reachable by train but the beaches are another matter.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the comments.  Gmap says it's about ~3hr drive by car to the tapestry museum, so return would be 6hrs.  Trains shaves ~ 90 minutes but as per answer below this might not be very pleasant anyways.
  (Regrettably the travel agents in NAmerica are quite useless and cannot offer more than what I can find using GSearch.  The canonical reply is: ask once you're in France :( )  Due to lack of serious options we might have to make this two separate trips to Normandy: not a bad fallback option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A day trip might be possible, but not much fun. The train to Bayeux takes two hours and a quarter, so round trip that's 4 hours and a half. From Bayeux to Arromanches or Longues-sur-Mer you can take buses, round trip of about half an hour. So that's 5 hours, plus waiting time, out of a day, just to go and come back.

That's the irony of the train system: it takes less time to do Paris>Brussels than Paris>Bayeux...